# How do i scan line and extract integers and strings containing whitespaces

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a file with following lines:

```
51:HD L80 Phone:78
22:Nokia Phone:91
```

I need to split these into 3 separate variables

```
(int, string, int)
int id = line[0]
string phoneName = line[1]
int price = line [2]
```

I have tried many solutions for example:

```
std::ifstream filein("records");

for (std::string line; std::getline(filein, line); )
{
    // std::cout << line << std::endl;

    std::istringstream iss (line);
    std::string word;

    std::vector<string> tempString;
    while(std::getline(iss,word,',')){
        tempString.push_back(word);
        // std::cout << word << "\n";
}
```

However in this example I do get the values but they are coming in a stream and not in one go. I do not want to save them into vector (no other way to store the incoming values) but call a function immediately after getting all the 3 values.

**SOLUTION**

This is a modification of the accepted answer:

```
`for (std::string line; std::getline(filein, line); )
{
// std::cout << line << std::endl;
std::istringstream iss (line);

for (int stockID; iss >> stockID; )
{
    char eater;
    iss >> eater; // this gets rid of the : after reading the first int
    std::string stockName;
    std::getline(iss, stockName, ':'); // reads to the next :, tosses it out and stores the rest in word
    std::string catagory;
    std::getline(iss, catagory, ':'); // reads to the next :, tosses it out and stores the rest in word
    std::string subCatagory;
    std::getline(iss, subCatagory, ':');
    int stockPrice;
    iss >> stockPrice;
    iss >> eater; // this gets rid of the : after reading the first int
    int stockQTY;
    iss >> stockQTY; // get the last int
    // iss >> eater;

    // std::cout << stockName << "\n";

    Record recordd = Record(stockID,stockName,catagory,subCatagory,stockPrice,stockQTY);
    record.push_back(recordd);
}
```

}`

for when text file contains:

`51:HD L80 Phone:Mobile:Samsung:480:40
22:Nokia Phone:Mobile:Nokia:380:200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use a `std::stringstream` here if you know you are going to have exactly 3 columns in every row.  Instead you can read those values directly from the file, store them in temporaries, and then call the function with those temporary variables.

```
for (int a; filein >> a; )
{
    char eater;
    filein >> eater; // this gets rid of the : after reading the first int
    std::string word;
    std::getline(filein, word, ':'); // reads to the next :, tosses it out and stores the rest in word
    int b;
    filein >> b; // get the last int
    function_to_call(a, word, b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much really elegant solution for when we know our input paramters. Also there is some issue where your code only iterates over the first line. I will add a working one above which iterates over both lines. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DeepakTivari Ah, Sorry about that.  I was just writing the code to match the input you had at the top of the question.  You modification looks good.

Answer (score -1):

You can find different ways to split a string here:

https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/04/21/how-to-split-a-string-in-c/

Example:

> ```
> std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& s, char delimiter)
> {
>    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
>    std::string token;
>    std::istringstream tokenStream(s);
>    while (std::getline(tokenStream, token, delimiter))
>    {
>       tokens.push_back(token);
>    }
>    return tokens;
> }
> ```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Don't forget if you are coping from somewhere you need to put it in a quote box.  Also this is pretty much what the OP has and doesn't want.